# Is there a better way to aim and shoot?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-hd-collection

I'm playing Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater in the HD Collection on Xbox 360.

The best way I've figured out to aim firearms is to hold down both bumpers, click the left stick to look down the sights, left stick to aim, and X to fire. This feels pretty slow and limited, and I'm finding it's just not cutting it for boss fights, The Fear in particular. Is there a better way to aim in this game?

Also, is there a way to move while aiming in first person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no better way to aim.

This is due to lack of a feature called "Pressure sensitivity" in modern controllers. DualShock 2 and DualShock 3 used to have pressure sensitive buttons. Back in the old PS2 days in order to look down the sights, a player would have to lightly hold the fire button and fully press it when targeting is done. I assume the game developers had to change the scheme to match the modern controllers.

Also, you cannot move whilst in first-person view.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and but I just found the solution so I hope this clears anything up if there are still people playing this game.

Take out your weapon with RT or R2. Go into first person mode with RB or R1 and then tap the Left Stick or L3 to draw your weapon without firing. While still in first person mode and with your weapon drawn you will want to hold down L1 or LB to aim down the sight of your gun.